# Detect error in Eclipse Ant builder

Tags: eclipse, ant

I have defined a custom builder for an Eclipse project (Project -> Properties -> Builders -> New ...)

The task that the Builder does is not important, since it is working correctly.

The problem is then: what happens if, for example due to the configuration of the developer, such Builder fails? An error is shown in the console, but the project is not marked as "failed". I would like the project to be marked as failed, since the developers are used to watch for red crosses in the Package Explorer and not to proceed if they see it.

Can I somehow configure the builder to do so? Any idea how? Any workaround?

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure exactly but a couple ideas:  
1. replace your regular java builder with a javac task and then use the 'Create problem markers from "javac" results' checkbox in Preferences->Ant (General)  2. detect errors in your ant script and then deliberately write some invalid code to a specific java file/class file to create the red crosses

Answer (score 0):

The [Laid Problem Marker](https://bitbucket.org/lii/laid_language_tools/src/master/se.lidestrom.laid.build_marker/) plug-in is a tool for creating problem markers from builder output.

The plug-in adds a *Problem Markers* tab to the build configuration dialog for Program builders and Ant builders.

Screenshot:

[image]

A custom build output parser can be created either with a regex or by implementing a parser in Java. The parser is passed the console output from the builder, and the result from the parser is used to put problem markers on project resources that appear in editors and the *Problems* view.

See to project description for details.

The plug-in can be installed using the *Install New Software* GUI from the project update site:

```
https://bitbucket.org/lii/laid_language_tools/raw/master/se.lidestrom.laid.update_site/
```

Disclaimer: I am the project author.